# No manual entry for chdir

Tags: 20.04, manpage

I tried to look up for this common error, but I was shocked to find out there is no one simple solution, all are very specific to the issue.

My issue is, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, that I try to run `man chdir`, but get this error message **No manual entry for chdir**.

I tried this set of commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y man-pages
sudo apt-get install -y man-db
mandb
```

Yet, it didn't help.
Please, what am I missing out?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu inside Docker container?

Comment: No, actually it's inside VirtualBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `chdir`-related manpages should be available:

```
$ man -k chdir
chdir (2)            - change working directory
chdir (3posix)       - change working directory
```

(man section 2 is for kernel-provided system calls, whereas section 3 is for calls provided by external libraries).

We can see where a man page lives (on a system that does have it) using `man -w`:

```
$ man -w chdir
/usr/share/man/man2/chdir.2.gz

$ man -s 3posix -w chdir
/usr/share/man/man3/chdir.3posix.gz
```

Then let's see what packages provide them:

```
$ dpkg -S $(man -w chdir) $(man -s 3posix -w chdir)
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man2/chdir.2.gz
manpages-posix-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/chdir.3posix.gz
```

So you likely need to install the `manpages-dev` package:

```
Description: Manual pages about using GNU/Linux for development
 These man pages describe the Linux programming interface, including these two sections:
  2 = Linux system calls.
  3 = Library calls (note that a more comprehensive source of information
      may be found in the glibc-doc and glibc-doc-reference packages).
```

Comment: Very very nice! Thank you for the elaborate explanation.

Comment: @InvestingTS you're welcome - I guess I should have qualified that you *might* want the POSIX man page, depending on what information you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing and searching for only a handful of man-pages, refer to @steeldriver's very helpful answer. However, if you are missing all man-pages as well as in need of all of them, you are probably using a [minimal](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal) system image. In that case, you can restore all the necessities in one step with the `unminimize` command.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to get the man pages back without unminimizing everything ?

Comment: @AnttiRytsölä according to [this](https://copyfuture.com/blogs-details/202207121726449764) post the unminimize command is a shell script with multiple steps, the first of which seems to restore the man pages. I guess you could easily kill the script just after that. I haven't tried this though.

Comment: With thanks to X Zhang, I had a look at the unminimize script. the server packages will only be installed if the ubuntu package "ubuntu-server" is installed. I had not, so it installed only mans, docs and translations.